# A name for a place where items are waiting to be processed

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, nouns

I am looking for a name that describes an area or place whose purpose is to store "items" that are waiting to be processed by some external entity. Kind of like a shopping cart whose purpose is to store items that will be paid for, but without the connotation of being related to "money".

EDIT: by "processed", I mean "subjected to the same set of actions", i.e. boxes that are waiting to be painted red, parts that are waiting to be assembled, ... Also, I refer to inanimate objects, not persons or living things.

Comment: You don't say what kind of business this is; but "holding area" is used for a number of applications of this type, such as a pre-operative waiting room in a hospital where the patient is kept prior to the start of surgery.

Comment: Would queue work? We have production queues, where products await the next phases of assembly.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the description. Queue would not really work, because there is no "implied order" in which the items are processed.

Comment: A *dispatch area*, perhaps?

Comment: @Pickle Why does queue imply that there is no order to which items leave? Usually a queue is a first-in-first-out type of thing.

Comment: The queue does not imply that. The word I am looking for should.

Comment: I think of "staging area" but the word "vestibule" comes to mind for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

An "***in-box/inbox***" should largely suffice. It typically implies "*a place for holding incoming documents/messages (needing attention)*" but the following definition includes "*incoming work*".
A variant is ***in-tray***.

dictionary.com:

> **[in-box](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in-box)** (or **inbox**)
>   *noun*
>
> **1.** a boxlike tray, basket, or the like, as on a desk, for holding incoming mail, messages, or work.
>
> Dictionary.com Unabridged Based on the Random House Dictionary, ©
>   Random House, Inc. 2017.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could very logically just call it ***Processing***.

If not, though, here are some other possibilities:

> [***Pending***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pending)—In the process of; during. While awaiting; until.
>
> [***In process***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/In+process)—Begun, and not completed.
>
> [***Ongoing***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ongoing)—Being actually in process; continuing.